# Finding the next date in a list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of dates (ann_date) and I want to find the next date in the list (ordered from oldest to newest ann_date) so that I have a second column (next_date).  I'm using SQL Server 2008 so don't have the LEAD function.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: My rate is $45/hour; please reply to accept.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). What is your table schema? Stackoverflow is a Q&A site where people offer their time for free to help answer questions, it is not a free code writing service!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ann_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ann_date) RN
    FROM YourTable
)

SELECT A.ann_date, B.ann_date next_date
FROM CTE A
LEFT JOIN CTE B
    ON A.RN = B.RN - 1
```

Comment: Thanks Lamak!  I didn't know about ROW_NUMBER().  Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to approach this. If it is only the next date you need then you might use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  Ann_Date,
        [Next_Date] = ( SELECT  MIN(ann_Date)
                        FROM    T T2
                        WHERE   T2.Ann_Date > T.Ann_Date
                    )   
FROM    T;
```

or if you need more data from the next row you can use `APPLY`

```
SELECT  T.Ann_Date
        Next_Date = nxt.Ann_Date,
        nxt.SomeOtherField
FROM    T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Ann_Date, SomeOtherField
            FROM    T T2
            WHERE   T2.Ann_Date > T.Ann_Date
            ORDER BY Ann_Date
        ) nxt;
```

You can also do this using analytic functions and a join. As always with no schema details or data it is almost impossible to provide the optimal answer for certain, so use execution plans and IO statistics to decide which is the best solution for you.

Comment: Thanks GarethD!  I had already accepted Lamak's answer above but I appreciate the more general answer.  I have never used an OUTER APPLY before.  It looks like a very elegant way to accomplish many tasks.